# localization in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, localization

I have tables with decimal type fields on Server.
I have published my web site to my local machine and to server.
In server it takes `.` as decimal separator but on my local machine `,` is decimal separator.
So I have ignored `,` with `javascript`.
Instead of `,` I am writing `.` with `javascript`.
So you can see that I have problem.
So what is a best way to Parse string to decimal?

p.s : I have changed decimal field to string in model

**we are using different cultures. 
But what I can do? Must I change my culture to server culture every time I will work with site?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the culture to match that of the client:

```
<system.web>
    <globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto" />
    ...
```

Comment: yes you are right. yesterday i have readen a C# book about globalization. And there was writen about globalization section in web.config file. and i tried it and it helperd me. Tahnks you too. it is final answer for me

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by differents cultures.

You can use

```
Double d = 0;
Double.TryParse(value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d);
```

or

```
Double d = Double.Parse("1,0", NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

namespace System.Globalization.

Comment: no it does not helped. if i post "1.10" as value it gives me "1,10" as out. but when i post "1,10" as value it gives me "110". In both methods

Comment: So, I guest that your CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator will be the comma "," as me and the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator will be the dot ".".
But, in InvariantCulture, the comma is the NumberGroupSeparator.
So, you need to standardize your number format...or use string.Replace...